# Where does Brasero store its images?

Tags: brasero

I'm using Brasero under Kubuntu 14.04 to copy DVDs.  Often it happens that I get a write error of one sort or another, so I want to try again without having to reread the source DVD. I assume the image is stored somewhere -- but where?

Anticipating this problem today, I set up Brasero to make multiple copies.  I figured that if the first copy is usable, great!!  And if it isn't, I'll just use the image it created to try again.  But I still have that problem: where is the image?  I might be able to find it if I knew the name under which the image was created, but I don't.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to not have to try again? I've found K3B to be far more reliable than Brasero,

Answer (score 0):

Brasero stores image files in the user's home directory.

You can confirm this (or the exact path of an image file by clicking on the ISO you want to burn. It'll open up a window asking where you want to burn the image. If you hover over the source (the image file shown in your project), it will display the full path of the image file.